# Trouble parsing '\\' when implementing a parser for a made up language in a Haskell assignment

Tags: haskell

I'm writing a parser for a language provide by a EBNF. Everything was going smoothly, I successfully parsed "if" "then" "else", "Let" "in", and infix like 1 + 2. But when I use the same approach for "\", "Nothing" is returned and I just don't know why. the EBNF describes lambda like this:

```
block ::= cond | lambda | let | infix
lambda ::= "\" var "->" block
var is a letter followed by 0 or more letters. I tested my var parser, it works
```

The **test** is set up like this:

```
newtype Parser a = PsrOf (String -> Maybe (String, a))
runParser :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
runParser (PsrOf p) inp = case p inp of
                            Nothing -> Nothing
                            Just (_, a) -> Just a
parse = runParser mainParser
testHandout =
    "handout" ~: parse inp
    ~?= (Just (Lambda "y" (Num 3)))
```

This is the **Expr** data type provided:

```
data Expr
    = Num Integer
    | Var String
    | Prim2 Op2 Expr Expr       -- Prim2 op operand operand
    | Let [(String, Expr)] Expr -- Let [(name, rhs), ...] body
    | Lambda String Expr        -- Lambda var body
    | App Expr Expr             -- App func arg
    | Cond Expr Expr Expr       -- Cond test then-branch else-branch
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Op2 = Eq | Lt | Plus | Minus | Mul | Div | Mod
    deriving (Eq, Show)
```

My job is to write the **mainParser**. The below code is the part that's related to this question (All code compiles with no error or warning)

```
mainParser :: Parser Expr
mainParser = whitespaces *> block <* eof
  where
    block = cond <|> lambda <|> letin <|> infixx <|> return (Var "Error")
    lambda = do
        char '\\' *> whitespaces
        va <- var
        keyword "->"
        blk <- block
        return (Lambda va blk)
...more code unrelated to question
```

for the line

```
char '\\' *> whitespaces
```

I've tried

```
operator "\\"
```

and

```
keyword "\\"
```

and

```
string "\\" *> whitespaces
```

non of them worked, I get Nothing as result everytime.
**FYI**, My given **parser library** related to this question:

```
char :: Char -> Parser Char
char wanted = satisfy (\c -> c == wanted)

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy pred = PsrOf p
  where
    p (c:cs) | pred c = Just (cs, c)
    p _ = Nothing

string :: String -> Parser String
string wanted = PsrOf p
  where
    p inp = case stripPrefix wanted inp of
              Nothing -> Nothing
              Just suffix -> Just (suffix, wanted)

keyword :: String -> Parser String
keyword wanted = do
    c <- satisfy isAlpha
    cs <- many (satisfy isAlphaNum)
    whitespaces
    if c:cs == wanted then return wanted else empty

-- | Read something that looks like an operator, then skip trailing spaces.
anyOperator = some (satisfy symChar) <* whitespaces
  where
    symChar c = c `elem` "=/<>&|+-*%\\"

-- | Read the wanted operator, then skip trailing spaces.
operator wanted = do
    sym <- anyOperator
    if sym == wanted then return wanted else empty
```

My testcase:

```
"\\y->3"
```

Expected result:

```
(Just (Lambda "y" (Num 3)))
```

Actual result:

```
Nothing
```

I know it's problem with "\" because I switched the "if" in my working if then else parser to "\" then else and the if then else parser instantly broke.
Also I want to at least try to get an error message so I added

```
 lambda = (do ...... ) <|> return (Var "lambdaError")
```

at the end of the lambda block in the **mainParser** but instead of a Just (Var "lambdaError") I still get Nothing. 
How to parse '\'? Or at least how to test what's the issue here?

Comment: Try putting `lambda` first in `block`, so something like `block = lambda <|> cond <|> ...`. (I'm not sure if it will work, but sometimes this sort of thing does work well.)

Comment: No, it didn't. But I think I might realize what the problem is. "->" is not being parsed correctly either

Comment: Can someone set this question to solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NVM I found the problem

```
operator "\\"
```

actually works but

```
keyword "->"
```

doesn't because keyword only parse letters, that's why I was getting **Nothing** when using operator "\". So I'm going to use operator "\" and write a parser just for "->"

This worked in the end:

```
    lambda = do
        operator "\\"
        va <- var
        char '-'
        operator ">"
        blk <- block
        return (Lambda va blk)
```

Comment: When I do that I get this:

>You can accept your own answer in 2 days

Comment: Why not `operator “->”`?